# Does DotNetBrowser support web workers?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, web-worker

I want to develop a customized browser with web workers(Dedicated worker) in WinForm(c#), does DotNetBrowser support web workers? or are there other suggestions for this?

Comment: Have you checked the DotNetBrowser documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, DotNetBrowser supports JavaScript web workers. You can try this yourself by opening the sample by the following link http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp in the DotNetBrowser WinForms demo application.

The demo application is available in the distribution archive which you can download on the product's website: https://www.teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser